# bookmarklet does not work in ie8 (but works in firefox 24 and chrome 30 )

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, bookmarklet

the following bookmarklet works fine in firefox, but when i click it in ie8 a window pops up but no content is displayed (the submit.php page should be in the pop-up with the correct values from webpage title, link, etc filled out)...

javascript:

```
url = "http://localhost:8080/submit.php";
Q = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();
L = location.href;
T = document.title;
pop = window.open("", "addEntry", "scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,
toolbars=yes,width=600,height=650,status=yes");
pop.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerHTML =
    '<form%20name="submitThis"%20method="POST"%20action=' + url + '>
<textarea%20name="title">' + T + '</textarea> <textarea%20name="link">' + L + '</textarea>
<textarea%20name="comnt">' + Q + '</textarea>
<input%20type="hidden"%20name="pActs"%20value="new"></form>';
pop.document.forms['submitThis'].submit();
```

...any thoughts?

EDIT:

if i modify the bookmarklet and remove the pop-up window portion it will work fine in ie8...

```
javascript:uri="http://localhost:8080/submit.php";Q=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:document.getSelection();L=location.href;T=document.title;document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerHTML='<form%20name="submitThis"%20method="POST"%20action='+uri+'><textarea%20name="title">'+T+'</textarea><textarea%20name="link">'+L+'</textarea><textarea%20name="comnt">'+Q+'</textarea><input%20type="hidden"%20name="pActs"%20value="new"></form>';document.forms['submitThis'].submit();
```

...so how can i get a pop-up bookmarklet to work in ie8???

Comment: with ie8 developer tools i can see that it is failing when it gets to... `pop.document.body.appendChild` ...i get the message "No such interface supported"

Comment: My wild guess is that immidiately after opening new window, `pop.document.body` is not ready for some reason yet. Try to wrap code that does DOM manipulation in `setTimeout()` call.

Comment: thx for reply.  i still get the same error when using setTimeout (although maybe i am doing it wrong)... i am starting to think it is a problem with my ie8 and missing dll's (see [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/no-such-interface-supported-in-internet-explorer-8/ff5620b9-b574-40ba-a617-e1cae1ac309e) and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/no-such-interface-supported-in-ie8/1ce28104-8976-412b-a0a5-84635da04db9))